# How to open image in a page with advert?

Tags: html, image, wordpress

I want to open image from an album in a page where I can also display an advert, similar to [this page](http://www.cinemahour.com/gallery/Monal-Gajjar/Monal-Gajjar-Stills-in-Pink-Saree.html). Clicking on any picture from this album opens the image in a page that contains some links (adverts). I also want to do the same for [my site](http://www.bollyhive.com/south-zone/tamil-actress-tapsee-hot-dancing-photos). How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like your site is being run using wordpress. In wordpress you can tell it where to link images too, I think there's a option to link the image to a html page that displays things in addition to the images.

Comment: Any detail information or support links will be a great help. Can you please provide some

Comment: To be sure Holly Sinner, Stackoverflow is very useful when you have code/markup that is not working correctly, not in creating posts of what you want.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments#Inserting_in_a_Post Under Inserting in a Post there's a part about "Link to the attachment post" that you should look at. Also look at step number 4 here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages .

Answer (score 1):

The link sample you provided is not opening images, it is opening a new webpage.

That said, you can configure your thumbnail to open a new webpage that has a full-size image with ads and other content.

However, since your thumbnails are opening an image directly, consider using 1 of many **lightbox clones** that are available. In particular, you will want one with `iframe` capability to show your ad content. Some are available as a WordPress plugin too.

**Reference:** [**Lightbox Clone Matrix**](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/)

**To clarify:** The lightbox clone will be opening a unique webpage that has a very large image along with your ad, which is why the `iframe` player is used, whenever a thumbnail is clicked on.

Comment: For suggestion on how that can be done, read `To clarify` above for method. As far as a tutorial link, you should use search engine to first learn about WordPress webpage creation. In particular, there are many YouTube Videos that you can [**watch**](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=make+a+web+page+in+wordpress).